# How to post custom data with GET method in forms?

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, get

I have a form that is used to submit a GET request for search page.

```
/search/?q=val1
```

I have included some other checkboxes to filter results, so now if i submit form it goes as

```
/seach/?q=val1&q=val2
```

I want it to be

```
 /seach/?q=val1+val2+val3
```

How Can i achieve this ?
I tried jquery but it doesnot send me to search url.

Comment: But why? You'll have to use JavaScript to compile the string, and lose support for non-Javascript clients for no good reason; then on the receiving end, you have to parse the string again. For what?

Comment: how can i append values of each form element in single name (q in this case that i require to pass in url to search)

Comment: What i want to implement is using one main search input box, and 10 check boxes .All values should be sent via GET to /search/ with only one name ie q=val1+val2+val3